# Select in Codeigniter is show is ambiguous error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have this functions in my model:

```
     function getIDByUsername($username)
        {

              $this->db->select('id');
              $this->db->from('users');
              $this->db->where('username', $username);
              return $this->db->get()->row()->id;

        }

    public function getData($rowno,$rowperpage,$username='', $title='', $tag='', $category='', $status='', $type='', $sort='', $order='') 
        {
 
            $this->db->select('id, title, duration, active');
            $this->db->from('videos');

            if($title != ''){
                  $this->db->like('title', $title);
            }
            if($status != 0) {
                  $this->db->like('active', $status);
            }

            if($username != ''){
                  $this->db->like('user_id', $this->getIDByUsername($username));
            }

            $this->db->limit($rowperpage, $rowno); 

            $result = $this->db->get();
            
            return $result->result_array();
    
        }
```

and I getting this error:

```
Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT id, title, duration, active, id FROM videos, users WHERE active LIKE %1% ESCAPE '!' AND username = 'testing'
```

My question is why this two selects is merged? This from getIDByUsername function and select from getData function?

My tables are:

Tabel videos:

```
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  title varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  description text DEFAULT NULL
```

Tabel users:

```
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: please specify which col from which table.

Comment: as per the error, it seems like you have the 'id' column in both the tables. specify the tablename from which id is to be taken.

Comment: @AqibJaved I don't understand you, look at my error, both selects from functions is merged

Answer (score -1):

getIDByUsername should return the user id but it returns an object

```php
function getIDByUsername($username){
   
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('users');

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    
    $query = $this->db->get();   
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return (int)$query->row()->id;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT `id` as `video_id`, `title`, `duration`, `active`, `id` FROM `videos`, `users` WHERE `active` LIKE '%1%' ESCAPE '!' AND `username` = 'testing'    Same error

Comment: try to specify
$this->db->select('videos.id as video_id, title, duration, active');

and in the getIDByUsername function

$this->db->select('users.id');

Comment: it show me:   `No tables used

SELECT * WHERE 'user_id' LIKE '%1%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 5`

Comment: same error `No tables used  SELECT * WHERE 'user_id' LIKE '%1%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 5`

Comment: show a schema of the videos and users tables

Comment: I have edited my question and I added videos and users tables